# How can I mount network CIFS folder?

Tags: mount, cifs

My `sw` ntfs shared directory is an installation directory on a windows 2008 server.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

I did the mkdir `/media/sw` and `smbclient -L` successfully... then while in root I tried

```
mount -t cifs -o user=username,ro //132.72.116.14/sw /media/sw
```

and got:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you wanted to mount the shared folder which was in the windows server. As a result, you got an error of user privileges, that was because you forgot to set the password of the windows server. Mounting the windows machine from Ubuntu requires you to set both user && pass of the windows server. You just need to use your windows server login details.

Comment: This username I'm using for mapping this windows share works fine from other windows platform. using the above command I'm prompt for a password and enter it. I also used the parameter password= to include it in the command line. Nothing help so far. Note that using the command smbclient -U username -L //IP gives a list of valid shares.

Comment: I also used it with varients of sec parameter like: sec=ntlm. still can't connect.

Comment: I was able to mount a win7 share by using option sec=ntlm. This does not work for the windows 2008 server. Trying to use sec=ntlmv2 mount option for the windows 2008 server share produces an error: mount error(22): Invalid argument